# How to collect a maximum of records per parent

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, limit

I'm currently working on an e-commerce project and I would like to create a landing page that shows every product category with per category the 4 latest products.
I'm using MySQL, plain query.

My database is fairly simple, there is a products table and a product_category table.
Of course there's a link from the products table to the product_category table: product_category_id.

Edit: i have created a db fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fmy7mBfZ2vcu7hhumU59ou/0

Of course, the sorting is easy, but i need just 4 product results per category_id.

Above the product_category table there is a product_main_category table, but I don't think this is relevant in this example.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, i have added a db fiddle link. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in mysql 5.7

```
SELECT
    t.`id`
    , t.`product_category_id` 
    ,t.`name`, t.`slug`
    , t.`description`
    , t.`price`
    , t.`created_at`
    , t.`updated_at`
FROM
(
    SELECT 

        `id`, `name`, `slug`, `description`, `price`, `created_at`, `updated_at`,
        @row_num:=CASE WHEN @p_id = product_category_id THEN @row_num + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @p_id:=product_category_id as product_category_id

    FROM
        products,(SELECT @p_id := 0) a1,(SELECT @row_num := 0) a2
    ORDER BY product_category_id, created_at
) t inner join product_categories pc on t.product_category_id = pc.id
WHERE t.rn <=4
ORDER BY t.product_category_id, t.id;
```

Which gives you following result

> ```
> id | product_category_id | name                 | slug                                                                  | description                                                                                                                                                                          |  price | created_at          | updated_at         
> -: | ------------------: | :------------------- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -----: | :------------------ | :------------------
> 17 |                   1 | Sandra Thompson      | dolores-quidem-vel-sit-consequatur                                    | Porro dolorem voluptas sapiente at debitis et est. Sed molestias qui minima enim. Et nemo ad sed voluptate recusandae optio quaerat. Est occaecati eos non nostrum voluptatem porro. | 103.96 | 2020-03-12 23:38:50 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 38 |                   1 | Mr. Domenic Kozey    | a-vero-quis-facilis                                                   | Reprehenderit fugit voluptatibus illo hic ut commodi. Deserunt maiores totam esse at voluptas et. Iusto et harum animi tenetur iste voluptatem.                                      | 195.03 | 2020-03-09 04:10:12 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 46 |                   1 | Rosario Schmitt      | eveniet-a-rerum-sapiente-iure-in-et                                   | Nisi delectus labore autem qui dolores beatae accusamus. Libero totam consectetur aut rerum atque.                                                                                   | 126.25 | 2020-03-13 02:12:21 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 48 |                   1 | Kaela Lueilwitz V    | ipsum-laborum-beatae-quia-repellat-hic-maxime                         | Magni non inventore quos. Et quasi itaque id. Corrupti sed maiores rem in.                                                                                                           |  43.01 | 2020-03-11 00:57:50 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
>  6 |                   2 | Jeremie Schneider    | sit-autem-molestiae-eveniet                                           | Corporis quidem aut nostrum suscipit in minima dicta autem. Nostrum porro dicta quo ut vero inventore enim. Repudiandae architecto voluptatem temporibus illo eum.                   |   3.77 | 2020-03-11 08:06:41 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 27 |                   2 | Devan Hickle         | eaque-explicabo-aliquid-architecto-rem-odit-atque                     | Molestiae molestias eos voluptatem vero sunt id voluptatem neque. Molestiae nam cum aliquid. Odio non ab et non incidunt sed.                                                        |  60.81 | 2020-03-09 05:34:30 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 32 |                   2 | Prof. Liana Torp     | quasi-eaque-soluta-sed-voluptates-odio                                | Voluptas est saepe voluptatem facere voluptates ratione. Esse rerum nihil deleniti nihil. Qui ut eum velit aut. Culpa rerum iure neque deserunt et.                                  |  67.77 | 2020-03-16 00:27:40 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 33 |                   2 | Abdiel Schowalter    | quam-sapiente-omnis-aut-et-rerum-perferendis                          | Fuga dolor dolore et in rerum at. Voluptatibus quaerat ab eum qui necessitatibus maiores et. Quam consequatur ea quia maiores qui consequatur reiciendis.                            |   3.53 | 2020-03-08 01:00:48 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 20 |                   3 | Mr. Eleazar Mante IV | voluptatem-consequatur-consequuntur-qui-veritatis-provident-dolor-quo | Illum sed eaque corrupti fuga. Sunt deserunt et iusto possimus id hic totam. Et voluptatem tempora nihil consequuntur voluptatem sequi quasi.                                        |  91.52 | 2020-03-08 07:44:49 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 23 |                   3 | Fredy Morar          | error-aut-excepturi-fuga-aperiam-sunt-illum-ea                        | Libero non numquam optio. Nam aut reiciendis necessitatibus voluptates. Molestias officia in est tenetur.                                                                            | 181.54 | 2020-03-30 05:25:37 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 36 |                   3 | Albina Hansen        | nam-et-labore-ipsum-quidem-aut                                        | Quo sequi consectetur quo amet quos. Eaque et velit aut quasi. Dolores incidunt autem blanditiis officiis dolor accusamus.                                                           |  97.39 | 2020-03-26 03:35:56 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> 44 |                   3 | Kenyon Mertz         | ut-aliquam-aut-modi-sit-sunt-sint-dignissimos                         | Dolore in corrupti sit et quis aperiam quia. Aspernatur aspernatur consequuntur voluptatem repellat rerum. Minima aliquam dolorem recusandae numquam voluptates.                     |  47.23 | 2020-03-21 10:29:19 | 2020-04-07 18:38:35
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f7b523f54d2065e7ec491e3a9bd4018d)*

The result is ordered so that you can see there are 4 rows per category.

So this order and the inner selct should be check or adapted

Comment: Thank you very much! I have applied it in my project, on real data and it seems to work fine. Could you please clarify the use of the two selects (@p_id & $row_num)? I think they are used to initiate a default value for those to variables?

Comment: yes, you can set it before the select, but this os more compact.

Comment: I have added a product_photo table which is a one to many relation, but this seems to mess up my results. Adding this inner join results in more than 4 results per category. Any advice?

Comment: look a join that give more than one row has a 1:n relation in your case 1:4, so to  get again 1 row you have to group it. Make a fiddle when you have problems. For the column that has 4 individual rsults you must use an https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I did add a group. I've created a new db fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpsk7ExkeagHPXHFFP3biL/0